# How do I dump an OrderedDict out as a YAML file?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml, ordereddict

I wrote a simple script that I finally use ruamel.yaml to publish out to a YAML file (example shown below).  I used `collections.OrderedDict` so that I can alphabetically reorder the keys, but even after re-ordering and converting it back to a dictionary using `json.load`/`json.dumps` I am unable to print it out in an ordered fashion.

I understand the YAML specification doesn't care about the order, but I personally would like the YAML file ordered, what's the correct method to go about this using the `ruamel.yaml` module?

```
logging.to_syslog: 'false'
statsbeat:
  multicast_interface_name: 'p1p1'
  primary_field_name: 'primary'
  udp_address: '239.253.0.50:20016'
  all_documents_index: 'statsall-${statsbeat.exchange_code}-${statsbeat.name}'
  exchange_code: 'd'
  primary_field_algorithm: 'range'
  cloud_type: 'none'
  primary_field_algorithm_range: '1-48'
  name: 'otpr'
logging.files:
  permissions: '0644'
  rotateeverybytes: 52428800
  keepfiles: 7
  name: '${statsbeat.name}.log'
```

Answer (score 1):

When you load a YAML file in `ruamel.yaml`'s default round-trip mode,
then a sequence is loaded into a `CommentedMap` (defined in
`ruamel.yaml.comments.py`). That `CommentedMap` is a subclass of
`OrderedDict` (or `ruamel.ordereddict` on Python2).

So one thing you can do is convert your `OrderedDict` to a `CommentedMap`:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap
from collections import OrderedDict

data = OrderedDict([
  ('logging.to_syslog', 'false'),
  ('statsbeat', OrderedDict([
    ('multicast_interface_name',  'p1p1'),
    ('primary_field_name',  'primary'),
    ('udp_address',  '239.253.0.50:20016'),
    ('all_documents_index',  'statsall-${statsbeat.exchange_code}-${statsbeat.name}'),
    ('exchange_code',  'd'),
    ('primary_field_algorithm',  'range'),
    ('cloud_type',  'none'),
    ('primary_field_algorithm_range',  '1-48'),
    ('name',  'otpr'),
  ])),
  ('logging.files', OrderedDict([
    ('permissions',  '0644'),
    ('rotateeverybytes',  52428800),
    ('keepfiles',  7),
    ('name',  '${statsbeat.name}.log'),
  ])),
])

def comseq(d):
    if isinstance(d, OrderedDict):
        cs = CommentedMap()
        for k, v in d.items():
            cs[k] = comseq(v)
        return cs
    return d


data = comseq(data)


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
logging.to_syslog: 'false'
statsbeat:
  multicast_interface_name: p1p1
  primary_field_name: primary
  udp_address: 239.253.0.50:20016
  all_documents_index: statsall-${statsbeat.exchange_code}-${statsbeat.name}
  exchange_code: d
  primary_field_algorithm: range
  cloud_type: none
  primary_field_algorithm_range: 1-48
  name: otpr
logging.files:
  permissions: '0644'
  rotateeverybytes: 52428800
  keepfiles: 7
  name: ${statsbeat.name}.log
```

(If you want the superfluous single quotes as in your example, you can cast the string
to `SingleQuotedScalarString`, imported from `ruamel.yaml.scalarstring`).

---

But what is probably easier, is to instruct the representer to
represent `OrderedDict` in the same way as a `CommentedMap`. Assuming
the same import and definition of `data` as before, you do:

```
from ruamel.yaml.representer import RoundTripRepresenter

class MyRepresenter(RoundTripRepresenter):
    pass

ruamel.yaml.add_representer(OrderedDict, MyRepresenter.represent_dict, 
                            representer=MyRepresenter)

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.Representer = MyRepresenter

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

with exactly the same result as before.